# merging multiple models in rails 3.2 so that users can log in under multiple subdomains using devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm using devise for authentication and am stumped by the way that my users are associated with the subdomains they can log in under.  I've studied the info plataformatec provides [here](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/tag/subdomain/) and the great post by Dave Kenedy on Ruby Source [here](http://rubysource.com/basecamp-like-subdomains-with-devise/).  I still don't quite understand joins and queries well enough to make this work, though.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :residences
  ...
end

class Residence < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :apartment
  ...
end

class Apartment < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :residences
  belongs_to :building
  ...
end

class Building < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :subdomain
  has_many :apartments
  ...
end
```

In `config/initializers/devise.rb` I've added:

```
config.request_keys = [:subdomain]
```

In `app/models/user.rb` I've replaced the default devise method, `self.find_for_authentication with:

```
def self.find_for_authentication(conditions={})
  conditions[:residences] = { :subdomain => conditions.delete(:subdomain) }
  find(:first, :conditions => conditions, :joins => :residences)
end
```

When I run my specs I get the following error:

```
PG::Error: ERROR:  column residences.subdomain does not exist
```

I know that somehow I've got to join my `residence` table all the way to the `building` table to confirm that the user signing in is affiliated with a building with the right subdomain but I don't know how to do it.  Anyone have any ideas?  The [Rails Docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables) has info on joining tables but that confuses me too.  (Basic info on databases and joining tables would help, too. ;-) )

**Update**

I've revised in app/models/user.rb

```
def self.find_for_authentication(conditions={})
  subdomain = conditions.delete(:subdomain)
  building = Building.find_by_subdomain(subdomain)
  apartments = Apartment.where('apartment.building_id' => building.id)
  conditions[:residences] = { :apartment_id  => apartments }
  find(:first, :conditions => conditions, :joins => :residences)
end
```

This might be a little closer to what I need but I'm still getting the following error in rspec:

```
1) UserSubdomainLogins signin should not be able to signin to building without access 
 Failure/Error: click_button "Sign in"
 ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
   PG::Error: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "apartment"
   LINE 1: ...SELECT "apartments"."id" FROM "apartments"  WHERE "apartment...
                                                                ^
   : SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "residences" ON "residences"."user_id" = "users"."id" WHERE "users"."email" = 'daniela@lehner.biz' AND "residences"."apartment_id" IN (SELECT "apartments"."id" FROM "apartments"  WHERE "apartment"."building_id" = 2895) ORDER BY last_name ASC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Which model has the subdomain field?

Comment: Sorry, @ShawnBalestracci, I should have been more explicit. Building has the subdomain attribute.

Answer (score 1):

In your revision you need to change apartment to apartments:

```
 apartments = Apartment.where('apartments.building_id' => building.id)
```

Here's how to do it using joins:

```
#subdomain is already in the conditions so you don't need to do anything
def self.find_for_authentication(conditions={})
  find(:first, :conditions => conditions, 
    :joins => {:residences => {:apartment => :building }})
end
```

See section 11.2.4 in the following guide for more information about the nested joins using hashes.
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables

Comment: Thanks, @ShawnBalestracci.  This answer probably works but I think I've got some problem with Devise that I've got to get worked out.  I hope to make that happen over the next couple days and report back.